# SQL show extra row informatrion as columns

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, pivot, window-functions

Consider the following table:

```
User   | Device
-------+-----------
User 1 | Device 1
User 2 | Device 2
User 3 | Device 1
User 4 | Device 3
```

How can I get the users for, in this example Device 1 each in a separate column?

```
Device 1 | User 1 | User 3
Device 2 | User 2 |
Device 3 | User 4 |
```

There can be more users per device than 2; in fact the max number is unknown

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    device,
    max(case when rn = 1 then user end) user1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then user end) user2,
    ...
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by device order by user) rn
    from mtable t
) t
group by device
order by device
```

You can expand the `select` clause with more conditional expressions as needed. When the users of a given device exhaust, the following columns show `null` values.

Comment: Thank you; this is a bit manual but at least it gives me the result I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Butting the data into separate columns is tricky -- unless you know the maximum number of users.

Often for this type of problem, the simplest solution is to put the values into a single column by concatenating strings.  The exact syntax depends on the database, but the SQL standard syntax is:

```
select device, listagg(user, ',') within group (order by user) as users
from t
group by device;
```

Comment: This is interestingl however I get the error: 
```The function 'listagg' may not have a WITHIN GROUP clause.```

I am using SQL

Comment: @Fimlore . . . You can leave it out.  That said, you need to tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Do you mean that I should tag it with SQL? because I did..
The exact version is 2016; enterprise

Comment: @Fimlore . . . SQL is a language not a database.